# Could someone assist me with that save form?

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

here follows the admin.inc file for my user's form.In this example i have `return system_settings_form($pppp_form);` what i really want is to make on my own a save button and save all that values when the user press save.... This form code bellow doing the same thing and it works but i want to do my own save-form because this form does not save the values that i want from checkboxes could someone help me to make my own form?? I really need help!! Thank you very much..!

```
/**
 * Settings form for the user.
 */
function pppp_admin_settings() {

  $pppp_form['pppp_key'] = array(
      '#type'          => 'textfield',
      '#title'         => t('pppp'),
      '#default_value' => variable_get('pppp_key', ''),
      '#description'   => t('pppp.'),
      '#required'      => TRUE,
      '#size'          => 28,
      '#required'      => TRUE,
    );

    $pppp_options = array(
      '0'       => 'No Values',
      '100'     => '100',
      '500'     => '500',
      '1000'    => '1000',
      '5000'    => '5000',
      '50000'   => '50000',
      '1000000' => '1000000'
    );
    $pppp_form['pppp_number_select'] = array(
      '#type'          => 'select',
      '#options'       => $pppp_options,
      '#description'   => t('Select how many values you want to check.'),
      '#default_value' => variable_get('pppp_number_select', '0'),
    );

    $pppp_severity_levels = variable_get('pppp_severity_levels', array());

    $pppp_severity_options = array();

    foreach (watchdog_severity_levels() as $pppp_severity_number => $pppp_severity) {
      $pppp_options[$pppp_severity_number] = check_plain(drupal_ucfirst(
        $pppp_severity));
    }

    $pppp_form['pppp_severity'] = array(
      '#type'        => 'fieldset',
      '#title'       => t('pppp.'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed'   => TRUE,
    );

    $pppp_form['pppp_severity']['pppp_severity_levels'] = array(
      '#type'          => 'checkboxes',
      '#title'         => t('Type of log messages'),
      '#options'       => $pppp_severity_options,
      '#default_value' => array_values($pppp_severity_levels),
      '#required'      => TRUE,
    );

    return system_settings_form($pppp_form);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The system_settings_form($form) function is a shortcut that allows you to build a form without having to worry about the save button/submit handler (those are added automatically).

If you want to build a full form including submit handler etc you'll have to define a form function and a form submit handler and then call it via drupal_get_form('MY_FORM_NAME_admin_settings_form'); 
So

**Define a form function**

This can have any name you want

```
MY_FORM_NAME_admin_settings_form($form, &$form_state){
  //Put your form array here- 
  //Add a submit button
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#value' => 'Save'
  ); 
  return $form; 
}
```

**Define the submit handler**

After this form is submitted it will automattically try to call MY_FORM_NAME_admin_settings_form_submit so we'll have to define the submit handler

```
  MY_FORM_NAME_admin_settings_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    //All the input is in the $form_state['input'] so we'll put it in a message to see what's happening. 
    drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($form_state['input'], true) . '</pre>'); 
    //Do your thing with the data 
    //Save it via variable set
  }
```

**Print this form**

Call this form via drupal_get_form where you need it.

```
drupal_get_form('MY_FORM_NAME_admin_settings_form');
```

Comment: i cannot undertand that:

Comment: MY_FORM_NAME_admin_settings_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    //All the input is in the $form_state['input'] so we'll put it in a message to see what's happening. 
    drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($form_state['input'], true) . '</pre>'); 
    //Do your thing with the data 
    //Save it via variable set
  }

Comment: i did all that things but is do not save my values :'( where is my error?

Comment: You have to still save the data with a variable_set('variable_name', $variable); The set message just shows a message with the structure of the input the person put into the form.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but I think you're looking for the submit button, which allows you to define a custom callback function where you would process the data.

```
$pppp_form['actions']['submit'] = array(

'#type' => 'submit',

'#value' => t('Delete'),

'#weight' => 15,

'#submit' => array('pppp_form_submit_callback'),
);
```

Comment: if i write down in my code that function and delete the : return system_settings_form($pppp_form) nothing is saved

Comment: You pass the data from the form and variable_get / variable_set in the callback function.
`function pppp_form_submit_callback($formdata){`
`variable_get('var_name', $formdata['pppp_number_select'])`
`}`

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: pppp_number_select in pppp_form_submit_callback()

Comment: print_r or dpm $formdata

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, you have 1 extra closing brace }.
For Form submit, you can add

```
$pppp_form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit'
  );
```

Comment: In form_submit hook, you should check what value pppp_severity_levels is carrying, by taking vardump of form_state

Comment: i am new in coding and i cannot understand what you talking about :/ :'(

Comment: i have no submit form in my code and i do not know how to create that :'(